# How can i Include a php file in a directory which contain include('xyz.php'); from another directory?

Tags: php, directory, include

My directory listing is: `Users>Images>PreDefines`
Where i am creating a php file i.e. `index.php` in PreDefines Folder. I want to include a php file from Users Folder i.e `include('header.php');`.
 But There is a problem. `header.php` file contain `include('title.php');` which not coming in `PreDefines>index.php` what should i do to include a file from another directory which includes others php files also.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply navigate with `../` which means go backward one step and then go wherever you want

Assuming you are in Users/Images/Predefines/index.php and you want to include a file in Users you say `include('../../header.php');`

Or for example you have another folder in users called assets which has a file index.php.
You do: `include('../../assets/index.php);`

Always include in absolute to the directory you are working on.
Something that might help php has `getcwd()` which returns the current working directory.
Also if you are going to change the server such as from windows to linux or other type of servers instead of `/` use the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant which will place a separator according to your server for example

```
include('..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'title.php')
```

Hope i understood your question